# Spring Autowiring (using @Autowired) for Defined Constructor

Tags: spring

I have defined my service as :

```
@Component("myService")
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
  public void serviceMethod(){
  }
}
```

And I am using this service in my client program is like below:

```
Public Class{
   @Autowired
   MyService myService;

   public void myMethod(){
     myService.serviceMethod();            
   }
}
```

But, In case I have below defined constructor in my service:

```
@Component("myService")  
  public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
      private myVar;
      public MyServiceImpl(String myVar){
        this.myVar = myVar;
      }
      public void serviceMethod(){
      }
 }
```

**Question:**
How can I autowire in my client program so that my defined constructor should be called?

Where below approach initializes object with default constructor:

```
 @Autowired
 MyService myService;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working that way...

Spring uses no-arg constructors to create beans and later it wires dependencies to those beans.

In your case Spring cannot know which String you want to pass to the constructor...

You can for example use java  configuration to create your Service bean (and remove @Component from your bean)

```java
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    MyService myService() {
        return new MyService( "some string" );
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Betlista. I got your concept and will see if I can fit your way in my application.